What parameter and threshold to choose to get significant pathways from MetaboAnlyst pathway analysis results?
MetaboAnalyst pathway analysis results give a total of 4 different p-values viz, raw p-value, -log10 pvalue, Holm-Bonferroni adjusted p-value and the FDR value. And an impact score.
Which value should be considered in my case (image link below) to get significant pathways? And what should be the threshold cut off?
Click here for Pathway results image
I tried to choose based on raw p-value< 0.05

I would go with the FDR adjusted P-value. The false discovery rate adjusted value is a less conservative approach compared to traditional methods, like the Bonferroni correction, but I would never go with the raw P-value especially if you are querying for hundreds/thousands of pathways.

thank you for your response. I would like to share the overall pathways results here https://i.sstatic.net/LhHKTAad.jpg for you to have look and advise me further.

It seems like that first pathway might be your best hit. I would play around with the pathway library selection on the parameter settings. (IE if you are doing homo sapiens theres different sources of the data). Or play around with the algorithm selection: GSEA or Mummichog.
